# Apps to make mathematics much interesting by sharing creative ideas with others

Tags: secondary-education, apps

I think proofs without words is much important topic when we want to improve students interest in subject using their skills other than in mathematics. Recently I could able to find that kind of proof for $$arccot(3) + arccot(7) +arccot(13)+...= (π/4) $$and
$$arccot(2) + arccot(8)+arccot(18)+...= (π/4) $$
I thought GeoGebra is the best app to draw the figures and share to others in full details. Here you have the links
https://www.geogebra.org/m/j5yvst8s
https://www.geogebra.org/m/vm4ffyvj 
I would like to know whether there are much better options and how to use these apps in much efficient ways.

Comment: One of the advantages of geogebra is that it is interactive. Are there features that you will want the student to interact with? In my world (secondary teaching in the US) both geogebra and desmos (https://www.desmos.com/calculator) are widely adopted at the elementary, secondary, and undergraduate levels, especially for creating graphs and other math objects the student can interact with. For this, geogebra would be better of the two.

If you are simply trying to create a graph for output, then perhaps something as generic as gnuplot  (http://www.gnuplot.info/) would do?